# .Resources.Match Returns Page Missing Resources

Tags: hugo, go-templates, toml, hugo-content-organization

A page on my site calls `.Resources.Match` to fetch a group of content files that I expect to have their own `.Resources` property, but do not. I would like to fetch the page, then get a resource. The content structure is like a page bundle, and I've added `[[resources]]` to the front matter, but neither `.BundleType` nor `Resources` is set (`.Resources` returns an empty array). How can I get the content, then the resource?

##### Directory

```
page/
├─ index.md
└- leaf_bundles/
   └- leaf/
     ├─ index.md
     └─ resource.etc
```

##### Template `page/index.md`

```golang
{{ $leaf := .Resources.Match "leaf_bindles/**/*.md" | index 0 }}
{{ $leaf.IsPage }} // => true
{{ $leaf.Resources }} // => []
```

##### Content Front Matter `leaf/index.md`

```ini
[[resources]]
name = "resource"
src = "resource.etc"
```

I assume that if I were to create a template for "leaf", `.Resources` would be populated in that context. Is it possible to fetch leaf bundle resources from a page returned itself by a call to .Match?

Comment: 1. Resources has nothing to do with front matter. 
2. Check resources docks in Hugo docs. 
3. Pages where Type is what is doing the work.

Comment: Here's the documentation on Frontmatter that includes a resources property - https://gohugo.io/content-management/front-matter/#:~:text=to%20hugo.-,resources,-used%20for%20configuring - and an example that a skosh verbose IMHO - https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-resources/#resources-metadata-example

Comment: Hi Jackson, yeaaah you're not wrong. The point is that .Pages where "type" "mySection" will return everything with type mysection irrespective of any resources.match work you're doing. Does that make sense? IF you want everything in a leaf bundle - just get the leaf bundle - no resources.match or page type stuff needed.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the desired result -- accessing page bundle content and resources from a parent page -- using `.Pages` and the `where` operator. Instead of calling `.Resources.Match` to fetch the `.md` file of a page bundle, `.Pages where "Type" "mySection"` returns the page bundle in its entirety, including a pointer to its resources. I set the "type" in front matter, and am good to go.

Thanks to misterbisson whose [post](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/solved-access-page-bundle-resources-from-a-list-page/14335) led to my solution.